# Selenium date picker issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to pick a date from  calendar so for that I'm picking all the dates using the below code but what i want is I need to get all the `<td>` tags from the calendar only but for now I'm getting `<td>` tags from the entire page . Below is the code:

```
List<WebElement> listofCalendardates=CommonBrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for(int i=0 ; i < listofCalendardates.size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println("the data is :: " + listofCalendardates.get(i).getText());
    if (listofCalendardates.get(i).getText().equals(finalDateValue)) {
        listofCalendardates.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way by which I can get only the dates from the calendar and no other data from the page? Thanks

```
<table class=" table-condensed">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="old day">30</td>
<td class="day">1</td>
<td class="day">2</td>
<td class="day">3</td>
<td class="day">4</td>
<td class="day">5</td>
<td class="day">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Can you add the table structure of Datepicker in the question

Comment: added . pls look above

Comment: @Joe Can you consider showing us what `CommonBrowserSetup` is all about? I don't find you setting up `finalDateValue` as well. Thanks

Comment: public class CommonBrowserSetup {
 public static WebDriver driver;
  static void browserOpen(){
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://192.168.0.193:8003");

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate the calendar object and use it to locate the `<td>` tags

```
WebElement calendarElement = CommonBrowserSetup.driver.findElement(...);
List<WebElement> listofCalendardates = calendarElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

Comment: calendarElement.findElements(By.tagName("td")); returning me a empty list with size =0

Comment: @Joe There is no much I can do without knowing how you located `calendarElement` and the calendar html.

Answer (score 0):

Use following xpath to get the  tags of only datepickers

```
List<WebElement> listofCalendardates=CommonBrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='table-condensed']//td"));
for(int i=0 ; i < listofCalendardates.size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println("the data is :: " + listofCalendardates.get(i).getText());
    if (listofCalendardates.get(i).getText().equals(finalDateValue)) {
        listofCalendardates.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```